# Angularjs ui:sortable in ng:repeat not behaving as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I'm trying to make a drag-and-drop editor for the values of an HTML `<select>` menu, with `<optgroup>` grouping.

I've been working in a JSFiddle; [here's what I have at the moment](http://jsfiddle.net/LBbGK/14/). It currently consists of a multi-dimensional array and two nested `ng-repeat` divs to display all of the array's content in groups.

The drag-and-drop portion is working (including dragging across groups, which I need), but the output of the model's contents at the bottom doesn't match up with what's happening above. Here's what I've been able to gather:

- If I drag any item down by one position (item or group), nothing updates in the model output below.
- If I drag any item down by two or more positions, the model output *does* update
- If I drag any item up by one or more positions, the model output updates
- If I drag any item across groups, the model output updates

I've done lots of googling, but I wasn't able to find any mentions of a similar issue. Given that the actual drag-and-drop portion is behaving as expected, I can't imagine what sort of issue in the code would cause the model to update correctly or incorrectly based on both drag direction and distance.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Am I doing something wrong, or is this just a bug in [Angular-UI Sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)? If so, is there an alternative for AngularJS that supports dragging items between groups like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a bug in whatever version you are using.

Using the latest version of sortable.js from the master branch it seems to work just fine:

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/master/src/sortable.js"></script>

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.sortable']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N58Qk/

Comment: Oh, awesome. I tried it with different versions of Angular, but for some reason I didn't think to check for a newer version of Angular-UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try Angular-NestedSortable, it's an Angularjs plugin that can sort nested lists and bind data, and dosen't need to depend on jQuery. https://github.com/jimliu/Angular-NestedSortable